# The story of a blind girl

Tags: steganography

Here is a story of the blind girl. I suggest you read fully and then answer the question.

> This happened when I was in Elementary School. I 
> was on my way home from school when I was stopped by a 
> a girl with long dark hair that stretched to her waist. I 
> cursed under my breath when I saw her eyes. This is a true 
> story. Her eyes were milky white and she was blind. "I wonder 
> if you can help me," she said. "I need to make a call. Can 
> you dial the number for me? You see, I am blind and I can't 
> read the numbers." She made me nervous. Something about 
> the girl just didn't feel right. I remembered an old ghost 
> story my mother told me when I was a child. It had 
> to do with the ghost of a blind girl who kept asking 
> the people who passed by to do things for her. In the 
> end, if you helped her, she would put a curse on you and make 
> you would go blind. The girl grabbed me by the arm and hissed, "You 
> will help me!" I was very frightened and she wouldn't let me 
> go, so I pushed her away. As I ran off, I could hear the 
> blind girl behind me, laughing hysterically.

Can you find something creepy about this story?

Comment: ummmmm literally everything about it is creepy

Comment: There's something particular which is creepy, also why the downvote? Someone please explain the downvotes, I cannot understand how this is a bad puzzle.

Comment: The down votes are likely because the question as posed can have many possible correct answers. I know what you intended the correct answer to be, but since the whole thing is a creepy story, you would still be correctly answering the question as posed just to describe any element of the story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "creepy" thing is

> that the first word of each line spells "This was a cursed story. If you read the story to the end, you will go blind."

Comment: That's it, you were fast.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the creeps parts I noticed:

---

1. > The girl grabbed me by the arm and hissed, "You will help me!"

Explanation:

> It is not considered normal behavior to grab a stranger by the arm and state condescendingly what that stranger should do.

---

2. > As I ran off, I could hear the blind girl behind me, laughing hysterically.

Explanation:

> It is not considered normal behavior to laugh hysterically for seemingly no reason, and a blind girl doing so just makes it more creepy.

---

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are looking for, but is the answer supposed to be

> How did she grab your arm if she was blind?

Comment: Not really the answer, some blind person can grab the arm only as you can sense where the person is. There's more creepy thing hidden in the story, look for it.